# Positioning div inside another div using display:inline-block css property

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a theme for my project but I'm facing some problem while positioning div inside another div.

below is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .mainDIV
        {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-color:cyan;
        }
        .header
        {
            width:100%;
            height:10%;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        .menu
        {
            width:10%;
            height:90%;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color:black;
        }
        .content
        {
            width:80%;
            height:90%;
            background-color:blue;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        .menuItem   
        {
            width:100%;
            height:10%;
            background-color:white;
            display:inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainDIV">       
        <div class="header">        
        </div>
        <div >      
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="menuItem">
                    I Want display content inside a DIV
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I position multile div. I'm using display:inline-block css property.

Comment: `div.menuItem` is inside `div.menu`. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: my div.menu is not positioned properly. it shifting towords bottom.please paste code in any online html editor,you will see "I Want display content inside a DIV" is shifted towards bottom.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be helpful with trying to understand how it is not displaying properly. Div's are nested correctly for me as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand or can't reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/00404upe/

Comment: Please Put entire code in http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/
You will see menuItem shifted.
In jsfiddle it is not giving proper output.I tried

Comment: I suggest trying `vertical-align:top` on `div.menu` and `div.menuItem`. See [this page](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/) and scroll down to "The Alignment Issue - display:inline-block".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your divs are not aligning correctly is because the default is `block` while you are setting `inline-block` display attribute on descendant nodes. This should be consistent throughout the entire structure. The next issue is that the default alignment on inline-blocks is "baseline".

You have two options:

1) add:
 `float:left;` in `.mainDiv` and `.menu`, then a `float:right` in `.content`.

2) add `display:inline-block;` everywhere it's not set and set a vertical-align property on the divs that contain the menu and content.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. Floats should not be necessary with `inline-block` elements.

Comment: Incidentally, the default for `<div>` is [`display:block`](http://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/).